# “Podfile” is damaged and can’t be opened.

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

I am unable to open or edit the Podfile

[image: pod]

when I try to open it in the terminal by "vim Podfile"

I can see the content of the Podfile as this.

[image]

How can I open and edit my Podfile?

Comment: the double quotes around TTRangeSlider are suspicious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the damaged one, initiated a new podfile with the previous content, then it worked totally fine. I don't know what was the cause, but this solved my problem.